# Haskell can't :load a File in ghci: changeWorkingDirectory: does not exist

Tags: haskell, ghci, intero

I'm in a ghci session trying to load a `Main.hs` file I've been working on.  It looks like I'm in the right directory in that I can see the file:

```
ghci    λ> :cd /home/username/codeplace
ghci    λ> :! ls
lib.hs        Main.hs
```

But I can't seem to load it:

```
ghci    λ> :load Main
*** Exception: code: changeWorkingDirectory: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Well that's a weird error.  Same for any `:l` variation I can think of:

```
ghci    λ> :l Main
*** Exception: code: changeWorkingDirectory: does not exist (No such file or directory)
ghci    λ> :l Main.hs
*** Exception: code: changeWorkingDirectory: does not exist (No such file or directory)
ghci    λ> :l 'Main.hs'
target ‘'Main.hs'’ is not a module name or a source file
ghci    λ> :l "Main.hs"
*** Exception: code: changeWorkingDirectory: does not exist (No such file or directory)
ghci    λ> :l ./Main.hs
*** Exception: code: changeWorkingDirectory: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

According to [reference docs here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.2/docs/html/users_guide/loading-source-files.html), it should just be

```
:load Main
```

Right?

Some potential sources of weirdness that may help a haskell wizard see the error of my ways:

- I'm running my ghci in an emacs session using intero.
- I have a custom prompt in `~/.ghc/ghci.conf`

eg:

```
  :set prompt "ghci    λ> "
  :set +m
  :set prompt2 "ghci     | "
```

Why can't I load, why am I getting this strange error about changing directories, and how can I fix?

Comment: Very strange error indeed... can you run `ghci --ignore-dot-ghci` from a regular terminal and see if it works then, to eliminate the possibility that your configuration (either .ghci and emacs configuration) are causing it? I can't imagine how it could be the `.ghci` file, but emacs/intero could certainly be doing very very weird things. (was going to try intero myself, but it doesn't even install....)

Comment: If this doesn't reveal the cause of the error, then you should also try `ghci -v4` (verbosity) and include the output from that as well.

Comment: Smell like `corrupted file` or file/directory `permission` problem to me.

Comment: Can you show the contents of main?

Comment: I had the same error a few times while running ghc provided by stack outside a stack sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I can't provide additional information as to what was happening.  Went to answer comments above after rebooting the next day and everything worked fine.  Strange.